# How to get http response Body when the status code is not valid?

Tags: c#, http, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm trying to get a html page content from a private service. 
The page returns status code 0, which is not valid. But the page do render when browsing through a browser.

When I try use `WebResponse.GetResponseStream(`) it simply returns empty stream.
And when I try use `HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url)`.Result, it throws `AggregateException` as follow:

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at DiagnosticInfoCrawler.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\TFS\MSNMetro\Tools\Verticals\Sports\DiagnosticInfoCrawler\Program.cs:line 47
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
   HResult=-2146233088
   Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 0 ().
   InnerException:
```

Two types of code used as follow:

```
WebResponse response = GetWebResponse(url);
responseBody = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
pageSource = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
```

Anyone can advise how can I get the response body? (given that I have no control to fix the service to return the correct status code.)

Thank you,
DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't resolve this issue directly, but instead went to the approach to use TcpClient to read the response.

Answer (score 1):

Catch `WebException` to get the response. This is a poor design decision by Microsoft since non 200 codes can be part of the normal case.

```
try
{
    WebResponse response = GetWebResponse(url);
    responseBody = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    pageSource = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)exception.GetResponse();
    //the response is here..
}
```

Comment: Thank you jgauffin, but the exception thrown here is actually a System.AggregateException, hence Catch (WebException ex) won't even catch.

Comment: AggregateException contains several exceptions. One of them is WebException

Comment: No, the innerException is a HttpRequestException, can't cast that back to WebException